# Duplicate rows in MySQL select statement

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have the following query:

```
SELECT word, count
FROM t_word t
JOIN t_counter tc
ON t.word_id = tc.id
```

Which produces something like:

```
'cab', 2
'capital', 3
'new york', 2
```

What i want to do, is have the results show up like this:

```
'cab',
'cab'
'capital',
'capital',
'capital', 
'new york',
'new york'
```

So that the count column, actually duplicates that row for my query. I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, as I haven't played much with loops in MySQL... Any  guidance is much appreciated!.

Comment: Does `count` come from the `counter` table?

Comment: Is it really worth doing this in the SQL? It seems like it'd be a lot easier to just process the data in your code and duplicate it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select T.word
From t_word As T
    Join    (
            Select 1 As Num
            Union All Select 2
            Union All Select 3
            ) As Numbers
        On Numbers.Num <= T.count
```

If `count` actually comes from the `counter` table, then you would do something like:

```
Select T.word
From t_word As T
    Join t_counter As TC
        On TC.id = t.word_id
    Join    (
            Select 1 As Num
            Union All Select 2
            Union All Select 3
            ) As Numbers
        On Numbers.Num <= TC.count
```

Comment: @Thomas: the Union All statement seems to be breaking up the query... get a bad syntax error, is the above query available for MySQL 5.5?. And yes, 'count' does come from the counter table.

Comment: @user550178 - That's my bad. I had a typo in my derived table which I've fixed. The should be `Union All Select ..`.

Comment: @user550178 - Fixed another typo in the second On clause which should read: `On Numbers.Num <= TC.count`

Comment: @Thomas, this works great, however, two things: in case the 'count' is, let's say 10 (as i get random numbers in here, not only from 1 to 3), would it be possible to make this statement dynamic? And second of all, I sort of get what you are doing, but not entirely, what's the logic behind the "Union ALL Select" inside a join?, Thanks for the answer

Comment: @user550178 - All that would be need to expand out to say 10 is to expand the Union All derived table to go out to 10. Basically, I'm building a numbers or tally table so that for a given count, I generate that many rows. Joins work by matching rows on the left side with rows on the right side. In this case, a given count > 1 can match to multiple rows so it duplicates the left side so that it can associate that left side row with each value on the right.

Comment: @user550178 - It should also be noted that the Numbers table could be static. I.e., a static table with one column and sequential list of integers that is populated once. This type of table is useful for some types of queries and could be used in lieu of dynamically whipping up a list of integers as I've done here.